# phpunits for dummies (howto and documentation)?

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, selenium-rc

i would like to have a documentation on how to use phpunits for dummies. is there any ? or do you have a great reference website that provide how to use phpunits on daily basis ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a TDD guide see: [php testing series - Invisible to the eye](http://giorgiosironi.blogspot.com/search/label/php%20testing%20series) or [giorgiosironi's Practical-Php-Testing at master - GitHub](http://github.com/giorgiosironi/Practical-Php-Testing)

And, you know…

There is a site dedicated for learning PHPUnit: [PHPUnit Manual](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/)